# Insert code into multiple files? Remove from multiple files?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have some code I want to insert into several classes but I don't want to do it manually, is there a way to automate this in visual studio 2008?

Can you remove code from several files in a similiar way?

thanks

Comment: You mean code duplication? What should that be good for. Be more specific about why you need that. Or make the code available in a callable method or in a utility class. And call that wherever needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio has a Macro feature that you might want to take a look at.

While I don't know what your specific scenario is, I would always be a bit concerned if a requirement like this comes up, because it sound like code duplication.

On the other hand, if you want to do this because you wish to provide certain templates, Visual Studio has this feature as well. You can create new file templates or edit the existing ones.

With templates, however, you can't remove code, so in that case, you would have to resort to writing (or recording) a macro.